# Does Soundpool play method create its own thread?

Tags: android, soundpool

When you use the play method with soundPool, does the method automatically create a separate thread for playing the sound (especially if you put it to loop indefinitely), or does it use the UI thread to play the sound?

I'm only asking because my application crashes randomly and I think it's because I over work the UI thread. Considering putting my soundPool loop on a service with its own process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoundPool may create several threads, depending on how it's configured.  Look at the set of threads present while your app is running (using `adb shell ps -t` or DDMS' thread view).  You'll see "SoundPool", "SoundPoolThread", and "AudioTrack".

"Overworking" a thread isn't really a crash cause.  You may want to post a new question here with crash details in it (esp. the logcat output); maybe someone can spot why it's failing.

Comment: Im sorry if is a noob question but where am i suppose to enter this command ? I think i can solve the crash issues myself if i only could get logcat to work , but that is a seperate issue :) This question was just aimed to understand soundpool a bit more, thank you :) !

Comment: ADB documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html .  DDMS documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html .  Note that most of what DDMS does is built into the Eclipse ADT plugin (http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html); you should use one or the other, but not both at once (if they both try to connect to the device they can end up stepping on each other).  logcat can be viewed with DDMS, ADT, or just `adb logcat`.